# Why i'm getting an error while saving images in python using Pillow?

Tags: python

hi everyone I'm trying to save images in python, using PIL, but when I run my gui application and when I save them an error occurs, the images are saved but not like an image. When I open them, they look like a text file...

This is the code I'm using:

```py
def save_all(images):                                        
    count = 1                                                
    for i in images:                                         
        i.save("image" + str(count) + ".png", format="png")  
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because the format is wrong - try:

```py
def save_all(images):                                        
    count = 1                                                
    for i in images:                                         
        i.save(f"image{count}.{i.format}", format=i.format)  
        count += 1
```